# Number conversion issue with Oracle database values where globalization culture is Italian

Tags: vb.net, oracle, globalization, decimalformat

I upgrading .NET Framework 2 application in Windows Server 2003 to .NET Framework 4.5.1; and Oracle Database 10g to 12g.

Currency values are stored in database as `Number(12,2)` e.g. value `416.67`

After framework upgradation and deployment the values displays `41.667,00` instead of `416,67`

Please note that globalization values are `culture="it-IT" uiCulture="it-IT"` and the conversion is done using following code

```
CType(dbCommand.Parameters.Item("column").Value.ToString(), Double)
```

I know that the conversion to `416.67` to `41667.0` is correct under the `culture="it-IT"` but I wonder how this were working correctly in previous Windows 2003 server? I don't have access to that server.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: The old behavior was arguably incorrect. Have you considered fixing the actual problem? Removing the `.ToString()` should do, assuming the statement returns the number as a `DECIMAL` and not a character type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I tried `(CType(dbCommand.Parameters.Item("out_imp_compenso").Value, Decimal))` and it throws error  'OracleDecimal' to type 'Decimal' is not valid.

Comment: read this : https://community.oracle.com/thread/2155678

Comment: Display formats are not stored in the database, that's up to the query or the GUI front end to determine.

Comment: and also check into your database after conversion to see  what value is in that field. and post :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906361/oracle-number-to-c-sharp-decimal might be useful. It suggests the use of `OracleDecimal.SetPrecision` to enable conversion to a decimal directly (with no string intermediates to gum up the works).