# Arithmetic operation overflow when running Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I've got a canned function in a class library to run a SQL query based on passed in query text. It works fine in most cases, but results in the error referenced in the title for a particular SQL query I'm trying to automate through it.

The entirety of the function from the class library:

```
''' <summary>
''' Attempts to execute the query provided and returns a datatable with the results (check for column ErrMsg to check for errors)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="FName">The name of the method requesting the query be executed</param>
''' <param name="path">The full file path to log any errors to</param>
''' <param name="QTxt">The query text to execute</param>
''' <param name="Close">Boolean to indicate whether the connection should be closed after the query is completed</param>
''' <param name="DB">The database to connect to (in case no connection is currently established)</param>
''' <param name="UName">The username to connect with (in case no connection is currently established)</param>
''' <param name="PWord">The password to connect with (in case no connection is currently established)</param>
''' <returns>A Data Table with the results of the query (on error one row and column added to return error message)</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function RunQuery(ByVal FName As String, ByVal path As String, ByVal QTxt As String, ByVal Close As Boolean, ByVal DB As String, ByVal UName As String, _
                         ByVal PWord As String) As Data.DataTable
    '
    Dim dt As New Data.DataTable
    Dim oda As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand

    'Establish &/or Open connection as needed
    Try
        'Connection established?
        If IsNothing(scon) Then 'scon is an Oracle connection variable associated with the class this method is part of
            EstablishCon(DB, UName, PWord, path, FName)
        End If

        'Is the connection open?
        If scon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            scon.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Capture the base error
        Dim msg As String = "Encountered an error while attempting to create and/or open the database connection to run the query for " & FName & "."

        'Log the error with details (EL is an error logging class from the same library)
        EL.AddErr(msg & " Error Details: " & ex.Message, path)

        'Put the error into the data table for return, so that we can handle it on the other end
        dt.Columns.Add("ErrMsg")
        Dim r As DataRow
        r = dt.NewRow
        r.Item(0) = msg

        'Exit
        Return dt
        Exit Function
    End Try

    'Build the command
    Try
        cmd.Connection = scon 'CMD is an Oracle command variable on the class
        cmd.CommandText = QTxt
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Capture the base error
        Dim msg As String = "Encountered an error while attempting to create the command to run the query for " & FName & "."

        'Log the error with details
        EL.AddErr(msg & " Error Details: " & ex.Message, path)

        'Put the error into the data table for return, so that we can handle it on the other end
        dt.Columns.Add("ErrMsg")
        Dim r As DataRow
        r = dt.NewRow
        r.Item(0) = msg
        dt.Rows.Add(r)

        'Exit
        Return dt
        Exit Function
    End Try

    'Build the data adapter & Execute
    Try
        oda.SelectCommand = cmd 'oda is an Oracle Data Access variable
        oda.Fill(dt) 'This is the line throwing the exception
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Capture the base error
        Dim msg As String = "Encountered an error while attempting to execute the query for " & FName & "."

        'Log the error with details
        EL.AddErr(msg & " Error Details: " & ex.Message, path)

        'Clear dt to prevent bad/partial data from being returned
        dt.Clear()
        Dim cl As New List(Of String)
        For Each c As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            cl.Add(c.ColumnName)
        Next
        For Each c As String In cl
            dt.Columns.Remove(c)
        Next

        'Put the error into the data table for return, so that we can handle it on the other end
        dt.Columns.Add("ErrMsg")
        Dim r As DataRow
        r = dt.NewRow
        r.Item(0) = msg
        dt.Rows.Add(r)
    End Try

    'Clean up
    Try
        oda.SelectCommand = Nothing
        oda.Dispose()
        oda = Nothing
        cmd.Connection = Nothing
        cmd.CommandText = Nothing
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        If Close Then
            scon.Close()
            scon.ConnectionString = Nothing
            scon.Dispose()
            scon = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EL.AddErr("Encountered an error while cleaning up from the query execution for " & FName & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, path)
    End Try

    Return dt
End Function
```

The SQL being passed in (blank lines added for readability):

```
SELECT to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - 
    to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 1) SWeek, 
    to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - 
    to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 7) EWeek, 
    fcp.concurrent_program_name PName, NVL(ro.ou_name, 'system') OU, NULL BGrp, 
    count(*) total_cr_executions,sum(round(((fcr.actual_completion_date-fcr.actual_start_date)*1440),2)) TRtM, 
    ((sum(round(((fcr.actual_completion_date-fcr.actual_start_date)*1440),2)))/count(*)) ARtM, 
    sum(round(((fcr.actual_start_date-fcr.requested_start_date)*1440),2)) TWtM, 
    ((sum(round(((fcr.actual_start_date-fcr.requested_start_date)*1440),2)))/count(*)) AWtM 

    FROM hotsosp.XXFND_RESPONSIBILITY_OU ro,HOTSOSP.HWC_FND_CONCUR_PROGRAMS fcp,HOTSOSP.HWC_FND_CONCUR_REQUESTS fcr 

    WHERE ro.responsibility_id (+) = fcr.responsibility_id AND ro.application_id (+) = fcr.responsibility_application_id 
    AND fcp.concurrent_program_id = fcr.concurrent_program_id AND fcp.application_id = fcr.program_application_id 
    AND fcr.Oracle_Session_ID Is Not Null AND fcr.actual_start_date >= to_date('07/12/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') 
    AND fcr.actual_start_date < to_date('07/12/2015','mm/dd/yyyy')+7 

    GROUP BY 
    to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - 
    to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 1), 
    to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - 
    to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 7), 
    fcp.concurrent_program_name, NVL(ro.ou_name, 'system'), NULL 

    ORDER BY 1,4,5
```

I would say it's a problem with the SQL, but when I run that exact same SQL through Toad it executes, as well as outputs to Excel, with no trouble.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

EDIT: 
The call to RunQuery looks like this:

```
oo.RunQuery(f, Epath, Replace(CRQ, ":Dt", d), False, "HAWCSP", UName.Text, PWord.Text)
```

Where `CRQ`is a variable that's hardcoded to

```
Public CRQ As String = "SELECT to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - " & _
    Chr(10) & "to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 1) SWeek, " & _
    Chr(10) & "to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - " & _
    Chr(10) & "to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 7) EWeek, " & _
    Chr(10) & "fcp.concurrent_program_name PName, NVL(ro.ou_name, 'system') OU, NULL BGrp, " & _
    Chr(10) & "count(*) total_cr_executions,sum(round(((fcr.actual_completion_date-fcr.actual_start_date)*1440),2)) TRtM, " & _
    Chr(10) & "((sum(round(((fcr.actual_completion_date-fcr.actual_start_date)*1440),2)))/count(*)) ARtM, " & _
    Chr(10) & "sum(round(((fcr.actual_start_date-fcr.requested_start_date)*1440),2)) TWtM, " & _
    Chr(10) & "((sum(round(((fcr.actual_start_date-fcr.requested_start_date)*1440),2)))/count(*)) AWtM " & _
    Chr(10) & "FROM hotsosp.XXFND_RESPONSIBILITY_OU ro,HOTSOSP.HWC_FND_CONCUR_PROGRAMS fcp,HOTSOSP.HWC_FND_CONCUR_REQUESTS fcr " & _
    Chr(10) & "WHERE ro.responsibility_id (+) = fcr.responsibility_id AND ro.application_id (+) = fcr.responsibility_application_id " & _
    Chr(10) & "AND fcp.concurrent_program_id = fcr.concurrent_program_id AND fcp.application_id = fcr.program_application_id " & _
    Chr(10) & "AND fcr.Oracle_Session_ID Is Not Null AND fcr.actual_start_date >= to_date(:Dt,'mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
    Chr(10) & "AND fcr.actual_start_date < to_date(:Dt,'mm/dd/yyyy')+7 " & _
    Chr(10) & "GROUP BY " & _
    Chr(10) & "to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - " & _
    Chr(10) & "to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 1), " & _
    Chr(10) & "to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') + to_Char(trunc(fcr.Actual_Start_Date) - to_date('12-29-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY') - " & _
    Chr(10) & "to_char(fcr.Actual_Start_Date + 1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') + 7), " & _
    Chr(10) & "fcp.concurrent_program_name, NVL(ro.ou_name, 'system'), NULL " & _
    Chr(10) & "ORDER BY 1,4,5"
```

`d` is calculated as follows

```
 Dim da As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1 * DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Today) - 6, Today)
 Dim d As String = "'" & DatePart(DateInterval.Month, da) & "\" & DatePart(DateInterval.Day, da) & "\" & DatePart(DateInterval.Year, da) & "'"
```

Which comes out to `'07/12/2015'` for today's date (7/24/15)

Comment: Are you getting an Oracle error?  Or a VB error?  If you are getting an Oracle error, what is the exact Oracle error message (including the ORA-xxxxx)?

Comment: It's a VB error. The exact contents of the Exception message are "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." There's no inner exception.

Comment: How is `qtxt` set? Can you show us that line in the calling code? This feels like the sql string might not be escaped properly.

Comment: Also, are you certain the failure is in this function and not further up stream?

Comment: For columns `ARtM` and `AVtM`, where you divide by count(*) use round().

Comment: @JNevill The certainty comes from watching the program run after first encountering the error. The line setting the `SelectCommand` completes successfully. @Ponder Rounding would alter the results as compared to running the query manually, which I'd rather not do. Also, since the query does execute successfully via Toad it seems like the SQL text is fine. If that's not the case, could you provide details as to why (so that I may avoid making the same, "Works here so it should work there" fallacy error in the future)?

Comment: Try to run query `select 1/3 from dual` - probably you'll receive overflow error in VB. And run `select round(1/3, 8) from dual`.

Comment: I found similar question, please read answers here: [Oracle number to C# decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906361/oracle-number-to-c-sharp-decimal).